# Need RegEx pattern string to extract portion of a text

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string:

```
testing_[Date{yyyyMMdd}]_[Increment{##}].csv
```

I need to match so I can replace the following:

```
[Date{yyyyMMdd}]
```

I also need the string inside of the brackets (yyyyMMdd) to be a group to reference to format a replacement string

I have tried the following pattern but it matches a much larger section of the string:

```
(\[Date\{(?<format>.*)\}\])
```

When this pattern is used then this is what is matched:

```
[Date{yyyyMMdd}]_[Increment{##}]
```

How can I just match to the following:

```
[Date{yyyyMMdd}]
```

Comment: I think you still don't know how SO works. We answer questions, not write codes on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier (`.*?`):

```
(\[Date\{(?<format>.*?)\}\])
```

Or a character class:

```
(\[Date\{(?<format>[^}]*)\}\])
```

However, I'd recommend that you specify just those characters you want to allow, like this:

```
(\[Date\{(?<format>[yYMdDhHms ]*)\}\])
```